# Undefined volume with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I wanted to translate this docker CLI command (from [smallstep/step-ca](https://hub.docker.com/r/smallstep/step-ca)) into a docker-compose.yml file to run with `docker compose` (version 2):

```sh
docker run -d -v step:/home/step \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    -e "DOCKER_STEPCA_INIT_NAME=Smallstep" \
    -e "DOCKER_STEPCA_INIT_DNS_NAMES=localhost,$(hostname -f)" \
    smallstep/step-ca
```

This command successfully starts the container.

Here is the compose file I "composed":

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  ca:
    image: smallstep/step-ca
    volumes:
      - "step:/home/step"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_STEPCA_INIT_NAME=Smallstep
      - DOCKER_STEPCA_INIT_DNS_NAMES=localhost,ubuntu
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

When I run `docker compose up` (again, using v2 here), **I get this error**:

> service "ca" refers to undefined volume step: invalid compose project

Is this the right way to go about this? I'm thinking I missed an extra step with volume creation in docker compose projects, but I am not sure what that would be, or if this is even a valid use case.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The Compose file also has a [top-level `volumes:` block](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#volumes-top-level-element) and you need to declare volumes there.

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  ca:
    volumes:
      - "step:/home/step"
    et: cetera
volumes:   # add this section
  step:    # does not need anything underneath this
```

There are additional options possible, but you do not usually need to specify these unless you need to reuse a preexisting Docker named volume or you need non-standard Linux mount options (the linked documentation gives an example of an NFS-mount volume, for example).

Comment: As is, this compose file will cause a volume named `ca_step` to be created, while OP's CLI example accessed a volume named `step`. This is no problem if the volume needs to be created anyway and you don't care for the exact name (or use `name: "step"`). However, if you want to access an already existing volume, you need to add `external: true` underneath the last line.

Answer (score 19):

Citing the [Compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes):

> To avoid ambiguities with named volumes, relative paths SHOULD always begin with `.` or `..`.

So it should be enough to make your `VOLUME`'s host path relative:

```
services:
  ca:
    volumes:
      - ./step:/home/step
```

If you don't intend to share the `step` volume with other containers, you don't need to define it in the top-level `volumes` key:

> If the mount is a host path and only used by a single service, it MAY be declared as part of the service definition instead of the top-level `volumes` key.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that docker-compose don't know the "volume" you created via command: `sudo docker volume create my_xx_volume`

so ,just manually `mkdir` to create a folder and `chmod 777 <my_folder>`, then your mysql docker will use it very well.

( in production env, don't use `chmod` but `chown` to change the file permission )